# The JSESSIONID of my AzureAD-SpringBoot application is expiring after the default 30 minutes. How to set up refresh token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, azure-active-directory

TLDR: I am not familiar with Spring security that much and is finding it difficult to implement refresh token mechanism with Azure AD authentication and springboot.

Our application is having AzureAD authentication with the default microsoft login page. Backend is in SpringBoot-Java and front end in in VueJS. The JSESSIONID is expiring after the default 30 minutes if there is no api request send to the backend.

When the JSESSIONID expires and a new request is sent, a new JSESSIONID is returned back to the frontend by default. When we try to make a subsequent request, this new JSESSIONID is automatically included in the request, but it fails again.

> We have decided to send a heartbeat/keepalive request to the server every 10 minutes to overcome this for now.

But I would like to know if there is any way we can handle the session/token in the backend and use this token instead of this JSESSIONID which is directly provided by Azure.

We have only configured the bare minimum for AzureAD authentication.

Following are the code snippets for any reference.

Snippet of dependencies related to azure

```
<spring.boot.version>2.7.0</spring.boot.version>
<spring.framework.bom>5.3.20</spring.framework.bom>
<spring.integration.bom>5.5.12</spring.integration.bom>
...
...
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>  
    <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory</artifactId>  
    <version>3.9.0</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

properties file

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=...
azure.activedirectory.client-id=...
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=...
azure.activedirectory.post-logout-redirect-uri=https://localhost
azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template[0]=https://localhost/login/oauth2/code/
azure.activedirectory.authorization-clients.graph.scopes=https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
```

security class

```
import com.azure.spring.aad.webapp.AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@Profile({"one", "two"})
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AADSecurityConfig extends AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sample/check").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And if it helps, we are able to fetch the current token using the following code.

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser;
...
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/token")
public ResponseEntity<String> getToken(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser principal) {
    try {
        return principal.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Token Not Available");
    }
}
```